# What's the best way to get or calculate usable screen space

Tags: android, android-layout

I trying to get the usable screen space for my app.  This would be the space between the Action/Tool bar and the Navigation bar.
Reason I'm needing it.  I have six buttons in a constraint layout chained together vertically.  At run time I need to resize the buttons.  The app has a fixed landscape orientation.
Ultimately I want to constrain the the bottom button of the chain to the bottom parent or nav bar (if it exists) and the top button to the action/tool bar.

I've found that there's an attribute resource for the action bar/tool bar that I'm constraining the top of the chain to.

For the bottom, my thought is to constrain the bottom button with a constraint guide. I just not sure how to find the screen position to position it at.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

There is one more way of doing this, if the previous answer doesnt work for whatever reason. In your layout editor, put buttons on the constraint layout and constrain them one to the other. Set constraints to be fixed, for example 8dp. The first button is constrained to the top of root layout, the last to the bottom. Lastly set the height of buttons to "match constraint". Am on mobile so I cant copy any xml, but this should force the height to be ruled by the dimension of root layout and lenght of constraint

Comment: I wondered if setting an OnLayoutChangeListener on each button would be the way to go.  I'll try that. What I'm ultimately trying to do is draw lines between the center points of these buttons and others on the screen, hence wanting to harvest the new 'Top' and 'Left' of each button.  The change happens when I run the app, and  the orientation is fixed to landscape. I'll see if this works an let you know.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Steps:

1. Get window height
2. resize images proportional to that height

add this code somewhere after setContentView or after inflation:

```
// root layout is the constraint layout which holds the buttons
rootLayout.addOnLayoutChangeListener(new View.OnLayoutChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onLayoutChange(View v, int left, int top, int right, int bottom, int oldLeft, int oldTop, int oldRight, int oldBottom) {
                int rootHeight = v.getHeight();
                int btnHeight = rootHeight/6;
                btn1.getLayoutParams().height = btnHeight;
                btn1.requestLayout();
                btn2.getLayoutParams().height = btnHeight;
                btn2.requestLayout();
                // and same for the rest of your views
            }
        });
```

Comment: Thank you.  How would I then go about accessing the NEW top and start position during the same run time cycle.  I'm trying to access the new center point of the button(image) during runtime.

Comment: there is  OnLayoutChangeListener that you can attach to a view and it notifies you of size and position changes. So, you can attach it to your root constraint layout and when it triggers then you recalculate with the above function. Am on mobile so can't help you with code but I'm sure you will find it in documentation easily.

Comment: @ Matic,  As this returns the old and new parameters (Left,Right,Top,Bottom) of my constraint Layout, in my case instead, would I not want to attach one to each of my buttons - so I could get he new left and top. `public abstract void onLayoutChange (View v, 
                int left, 
                int top, 
                int right, 
                int bottom, 
                int oldLeft, 
                int oldTop, 
                int oldRight, 
                int oldBottom)`

Comment: I just came home and spent a few minutes to write and test the code. I will update the answer with code and explanation.

Comment: @Matic, The OnLayoutChangeListener worked. In my post I added a screenshot of my debug run.  You can see where I added a block to retrieve the dimensions before and the dimensions after.  They returned  the same results, shouldn't the after 'dimensions' reflect the change.  
How can I retrieve the new(after) dimensions? 

thanks for helping!

Comment: Does the change happen when you run the app and resize the layout? How do you resize the layout in the first place? If you are switching horizontal to vertical then you should make sepparate layout files. If just resizing my code should work. And lastly if you just need those dimensions then try to add a layout change listener to the button aswel, and get new dimensions from inside that. Good luck